# How to call ffmpeg with arguments from C using popen on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, ffmpeg, popen

I tried to use `ffmpeg` concatenation with `popen` command in C but I get "No such file or directory". If I use Linux terminal with the same command it works.

C code:

```
fp=popen("ffmpeg -i \"concat: audio/1.mp3|audio/2.mp3\" -acodec copyoutput.mp3", "r");
pclose(fp);
```

Error in Linux shell:

```
audio/1.mp3|audio/2.mp3 No such file of directory found
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: have you tried changing the forward slashes / to backward slashes \?

Comment: It's not the problem. Just tried

Comment: You need to set the path for where the executable is

Comment: There shouldn't be a space after `concat:`.

Comment: Which executable?